# How to display mp4 then pause and replay in Flash CC

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I’m resurrecting a simple banner where we used an FLV movie and the following code to have the movie pause using setInterval and then play again. It’s a simple butterfly movie that flaps it’s wings and then goes back to a static state.

Looks like FLVs are now discouraged in the more recent Flash versions so I would like to know how to make a movie play, then pause using setInterval, then replay.

Here is the working AS3 when using an FLV on the Timeline in a frame based animation but does not work with an imported .mp4:

```
stop(); 
function timesUp()
{ 
gotoAndPlay(1,"Scene 1"); 
clearInterval(itv); 
} 
var itv=setInterval(timesUp, 15000);
```

Do the new suggested methods use a single frame movie where you load and play the mp4, then use setInterval as a timer to replay?

I can’t find any tutorials that have this method as an example.

I did read a tutorial on the Adobe site but the following did not load and play the movie (morpho.mp4)

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null);
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
addChild(vid);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler); 
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void 
{ 
// handle netStatus events, described later 
} 

function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
{ 
// ignore error 
}
vid.attachNetStream(ns);

ns.play("morpho.mp4");
```

Comment: I tested you code and it works without problem. Can you add `trace(event.info.code)` into the `netStatusHandler`, may by your video was not found.

Comment: akmzo - you were correct. Thank you. I added the trace which showed the .mp4 was not in the same/root directory as the movie. It works to display though takes up the whole stage and turns the next question to how to integrate the setInterval and replay?

Comment: I tried to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
import flash.utils.Timer
import flash.events.TimerEvent

var video_playing:Boolean = false, 
    timer:Timer,
    nc:NetConnection,
    ns:NetStream,
    video:Video,
    video_name:String = 'video.mp4'

nc = new NetConnection()
nc.connect(null)

ns = new NetStream(nc)
ns.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS,netStatusHandler); 
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 

function netStatusHandler(event:NetStatusEvent):void {      
    switch (event.info.code){
        case 'NetStream.Play.Start' :
            if(timer.currentCount == 0){
                timer.start()
            }
        break       
    }   
} 
function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void { 
}

video = new Video(135, 135) // set the size of video to 135x135px
video.x = 165               // set the left of video to 300 - 135 = 165px
video.y = 0                 // set the top of video to 0
video.attachNetStream(ns)
addChild(video)

timer = new Timer(1000, 3) // 3 seconds, just for example
timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, timer_on_Complete)
function timer_on_Complete(e:TimerEvent){
    if(video_playing){
        video_playing = false
        ns.close()
    } else {
        start_video()
    }
    timer.reset()
    timer.start()
}

start_video()

function start_video(){
    ns.play(video_name)
    video_playing = true
}
```

Comment: akmozo - works perfectly. Thanks.
Question: The mp4 is 135 x 135 located on the right side of a 300 x 135 stage. There is a logo on the left that I have on the timeline, but now the mp4 covers this. What code should I explore to learn how to size and position the mp4?